# What type of conifer is this?

Tags: identification, trees, conifers

While I was on my holiday in Greece, I passed by some nice looking conifers at one resort. I'm trying to find out what type they are. At first I thought they are some kind of thuja but now I'm not that sure. Can you guys help me identify them ?

[image: Thuja from Greece] 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

On the limited information available it seems the possibilities are numerous and, given the OP seems not to have revisited in nine months, little point in requesting further details from him. Anyway, if on holiday at the time, details of leaves, flowers, seeds etc might not be readily available. So I am just suggesting one possibility:

[*Abies cephalonica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abies_cephalonica)

[image: Abies cephalonica]
(*Image courtesy [gterez at Flickr](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Abies_cephalonica_forest_Petrouli.jpg)*)

Answer (score 0):

Thuja? Yellowness of the foliage suggests that, but the exact variety I couldn't say...